How to modify the request body in a Spring WebFlux filter?
I have a Spring Boot application using WebFlux, and I'm trying to modify the request body within a WebFilter. Specifically, every incoming request contains a header called user, and all the POST request body contains an attribute updateUser. The goal is to set the updateUser field in the request body to the value of the user header.
All the request body implements an interface MyRequest:
public interface MyRequest {
    String getUpdateUser();
    void setUpdateUser(String updateUser);
}

For example, my request body looks like this:
{
    "updateUser": "oldUser",
    "otherField": "someValue"
}

I understand that in Spring WebFlux, the request body is immutable and can only be consumed once. I've tried using DataBuffer but could not make it work. What is the correct way to modify the request body in a WebFilter and ensure the modified body is available downstream?
@Component
@Slf4j
public class IdentityFilter implements WebFilter {


  @SneakyThrows
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
  String userFullName = Optional.ofNullable(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get(USER)).orElse(List.of("")).get(0);

  // add userFullName in the request body
  }
}


I had to access the DataBuffer and change the request body by reading the bytes. There was no direct way to do this change.
@SneakyThrows
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
String userFullName = Optional.ofNullable(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get(USER)).orElse(List.of("")).get(0);

    return addUser(exchange, userFullName)
        .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.just(exchange))
        .flatMap(modifiedExchange -> chain.filter(modifiedExchange));

}


private Mono<ServerWebExchange> addUser(ServerWebExchange exchange, String userFullName) {
    ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
    HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
    if (!Set.of(HttpMethod.POST, HttpMethod.PUT, HttpMethod.PATCH).contains(request.getMethod()) &&
        !(headers.getContentType() != null && headers.getContentType().includes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))) {
      return Mono.just(exchange);
    }

    return DataBufferUtils.join(request.getBody())
        .flatMap(dataBuffer -> {
          byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
          dataBuffer.read(bytes);
          DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
          String requestBody = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
          try {
            Map<String, Object> bodyMap = objectMapper.readValue(requestBody, Map.class);
            
            bodyMap.put("updateUser", userFullName);
            String modifiedBody = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(bodyMap);
            DataBuffer modifiedBuffer = exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(modifiedBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            ServerHttpRequest modifiedRequest = new ServerHttpRequestDecorator(request) {
              @Override
              public @NonNull Flux<DataBuffer> getBody() {
                return Flux.just(modifiedBuffer);
              }
            };

            ServerWebExchange modifiedExchange = exchange.mutate().request(modifiedRequest).build();
            return Mono.just(modifiedExchange);

          } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error adding user", e);
            return Mono.just(exchange);
          }
        });
}

